# EditText in ListView is not editable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext

I am trying to build a form using an EditText view that is nested in a ListView. There are a couple of levels of RelativeLayout and LinearLayout objects between the ListView and the EditText, but from what I've read this shouldn't be a problem.

I've tried all I can think of. I have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the AndroidManifest for my activity, and I have set `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` for my ListView as well. I have even set that for all layout objects between the ListView and the EditText. However, none of this seems to work.

The main issue I have is the soft keyboard doesn't show up, and even when I double tap the text field to pull up the editing options I still cannot type anything into the EditText area. Am I just flat out using the wrong object control for this?

This is the layout code for my ListView object.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/FormlistView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    style="@style/KelFormListView" />
```

This is the layout code for my form_list_item.xml file. This is the item that is displayed in the form list.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">

    <!-- Top Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:id="@+id/TopLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Headling Rent (pa)"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            style="@style/KelFormListItemLabel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:background="@color/formListItemValueBackgroundColor">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/CurrencyIconView"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_currency_pound"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/ValueTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="20,000"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:editable="true"
                style="@style/KelFormListItemValue"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Bottom Layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:id="@+id/BottomLayout"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TopLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BottomTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Headling Rent (pa)"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            style="@style/KelFormListItemLabel" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:background="@color/formListItemValueBackgroundColor">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/BottomCurrencyIconView"
                android:layout_width="22dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_currency_pound"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/BottomValueTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="20,000"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:editable="true"
                style="@style/KelFormListItemValue"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out my own issue. The primary issue had nothing todo with any of my code. The problem was actually the emulator it's self. When creating a new virtual device in Android ADV there is a settings called "Enable Keyboard", or something along those lines. This setting allows you to use your hardware keyboard with the emulator, but it prevents the soft keyboard from showing up. That was my problem.

In my opinion this setting can easily cause confusion since it's not until you display the advanced settings that it appears. This just seems to me to be a poor decision that someone over at Google has made. Yet another reason why iOS development is easier...in my opinion of-course.